# How do Ioop through all controls and act on certain ones?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have an iPad application that adds buttons at runtime based on where the user touches within the view.

Now - I need to remove all these buttons at once.

I have set the tag of each button to be very high and grouped by type of button that was dropped.

How do I loop through all the button on the view and remove them if they fall into the right classification??

Comment: You should consider selecting answers on your unanswered questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This removes all UIButtons. Adopt it to your needs. If you want to use tags I would recommend to tag every button that should stay in the view.

```
for (id object in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [object removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Or you could add each UIButton to an NSMutableSet when you create them, and delete every button of the set if you don't need them anymore.

Comment: yup, and i added a look at the tag....  each of the custom buttons have a unique tag ID, and when i looped through the controls, if the unique ID was found, it was washed away.   thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only tag-based method is UIView#viewForTag and it returns a single object. (I believe it's the last view you added with that tag).  But, you can adapt the above code for your purposes:

```
for (UIView *iView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (iView.tag == TARGET_CLASSIFICATION_TYPE) {
        [iView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```